# Node.js get HTTP_USER_AGENT and Block HTTrack

Tags: javascript, node.js, user-agent, httrack

I want to block all bots (like a HTTrack) on my website. Normally, I would use .htaccess file to block bots via `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} HTTrack [NC,OR]`.

However, my server is running Node.js Express. How can I get HTTP_USER_AGENT and do a block or rewritecond on Node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a middleware for that, called [express-nobots](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-nobots):

```
var noBots = require('express-nobots');

// must be the first middleware
app.use(noBots());
```

You can see the list of blocked bots [inside a source file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jeremyscalpello/express-nobots/master/lib/bots.js).

Comment: thank you i installed and it didnt work then i realise in bots.js they write HTTrack wrong i changed and BAM! it's work thanks i think we must send mail about this